# Mapping nonlinear systems into linear ones

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

This is a request for references. I'm not asking for the answer... Just give me a starting point! I'm interested in global linearization of linear equations. I guess the problem is well understood in math given its simplicity, but under "linearization" I only find local linearization (e.g. near equilibria), which I'm not interested in.

Consider a linear system of equations
$$\dot{x} = L x $$
where $x$ is a vector. Now perform an invertible transformation $x \to y=f(x)$. In the new variables the system is in general nonlinear
$$\dot{y} = f' L f^{-1} (y) $$
where $f'$ denotes the Jacobian matrix.

Now let's pose an inverse problem: Given a generic nonlinear system
$$\dot{y}=F(y)$$
which general conditions should $F$ satisfy for there to exist a linear map $L$ and a transformation $f$ such that $F=f' L f^{-1}$? I would expect the answer to involve geometric concepts, like geodesic transport, parallelizability and the such...

Comment: Isn't that asking for the Abel-function/Abel-equation for F? see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation 

Answer (score 1):

Relaxing the hypothesis that $f$ is invertible, a sufficient condition to linearize globally the system with a change of variables $f$ is that $F$ is analytic. Then the Carleman linearization technique and other similar techniques (as can be seen in the book ["Nonlinear dynamical systems and Carleman Linearization"](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=KmjnMu6Qe20C)) can be applied to transform the nonlinear system in a infinite dimensional linear system.

Answer (score 0):

If the non-wandering set of Your system consists only of one equilibrium, Your local linearization will be global. You could also find a kind of global linearization (stable and unstable manifolds) with respect to a hyperbolic non-wandering set resp. hyperbolic measures, see for instance Katok, Hasselblatt: Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems. But your condition on a global linearization seems to be to strong in this setting.

Comment: I have to think about this... Does this mean that a dynamical system can be linearized all over a neighborhood of an equilibrium point that is locally asymptotically stable, via a variable transformation?